# Azure SQL DB allow NULL values for UNIQUE constraint columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

How can I set a UNIQUE constraint in Azure SQL database that allows NULL values in the column?

The below workaround from SQL Server doesn't seem to work in Azure SQL:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Email] ON [dbo].[Users]([Email] ASC)
WHERE ([Email] IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work in Azure SQL" mean?  what's the error?

Comment: Just tried your syntax on a test table and worked fine. You need to define what "doesn't seem to work" means, and it *seems to work* just fine.

Comment: I get this error if I try to insert a second NULL value into the Email column:
Violation of UNIQUE KEY Constraint "UQ_Users_5120...". Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>).

Comment: I'd suggest posting your actual SQL statements, including the table definition

Comment: Sounds like you (also) have a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the column, @OliverNilsen . Unlike a `UNIQUE INDEX`, you cannot create a filtered `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`. Drop the `CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: Note, as well, that the error doesn't even reference the index you created. `UQ_Users_5120...` <> `IX_Email`.

Comment: I had a UNIQUE key Constraint on the EMAIL column that should be there. After I removed this the Index Script that I posted in the code works as intended. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error, which is in the comments is telling you the problem:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY Constraint "UQ_Users_5120...". Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is ().

Firstly, notice that the error states "UNIQUE KEY **Constraint**", emphasis mine. *Not* Index, Constraint. Also note that name of said constraint: `UQ_Users_5120...` That isn't the name of the object you created (`IX_Email`).

You can replicate this problem with the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn varchar(10) NULL);
GO
--Create a UNIQUE Constraint
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_SomeColumn UNIQUE (SomeColumn);
GO
--Create a filtered unique index
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UX_SomeColumn_NotNull ON dbo.SomeTable(SomeColumn)
WHERE SomeColumn IS NOT NULL;
GO
--Initial Insert
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn)
VALUES('asdfasd'),
      ('asdasd'),
      (NULL);
GO
--Insert another dupe, non NULL value. Fails
--This violates constraint 'UQ_SomeColumn'
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn)
VALUES('asdfasd');
GO
--Insert another dupe, NULL value. Fails
--This violates constraint 'UQ_SomeColumn'
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn)
VALUES(NULL);
GO
```

You can fix this my dropping your `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`. We don't have the full name, but for the above example it would be the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable DROP CONSTRAINT UQ_SomeColumn;
GO
```

And then we can test again:

```sql
--Insert another dupe, non NULL value. Fails
--Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.SomeTable' with unique index 'UX_SomeColumn_NotNull'. The duplicate key value is (asdfasd).
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn)
VALUES('asdfasd');

--Insert another dupe, NULL value. Success
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn)
VALUES(NULL);
GO
```

*Notice as well, that the error for the duplicate value is *completely* different now. It mentions a unique index, not a unique key constraint, and has the name of the unique filtered index created, not something else.*

Comment: My problem was that I also had a UNIQUE key constraint on the EMAIL column. After removing it everything worked as intended.

Comment: *"My problem was that I also had a UNIQUE key constraint on the EMAIL column."* yes, this is *exactly* what I said was the problem

Comment: Yes thank you. Is it possible to delete this question all together as it is just noisy?

Comment: That would strongly frowned upon, @OliverNilsen . Users, like myself, don't appreciate it when you ask a question, we out effort into answering it, and then when you ge the answer you delete the entire question (including the answers).